# amCharts - document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I'm using amCharts to display a map. I'm aiming to change the color of a specify country using Javascript.

I do use the following line to change the color inside my web browser :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("amcharts-map-area-FR")[0].setAttribute("fill", color);
```

But when I use it inside my html page, this does not work.

Here is the full html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>map created with amCharts | amCharts</title>
        <meta name="description" content="map created using amCharts pixel map generator" />

        <!--
            This map was created using Pixel Map Generator by amCharts and is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.
            You may use this map the way you see fit as long as proper attribution to the name of amCharts is given in the form of link to http://pixelmap.amcharts.com/
            To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

            If you would like to use this map without any attribution, you can acquire a commercial license for the JavaScript Maps - a tool that was used to produce this map.
            To do so, visit amCharts Online Store: http://www.amcharts.com/online-store/
        -->

        <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>

        <!-- amCharts javascript code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AmCharts.makeChart("map",{
                    "type": "map",
                    "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
                    "addClassNames": true,
                    "fontSize": 15,
                    "color": "#FFFFFF",
                    "backgroundAlpha": 1,
                    "backgroundColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
                    "dataProvider": {
                        "map": "worldLow",
                        "getAreasFromMap": true,
                        "images": [
                            {
                                "top": 40,
                                "left": 60,
                                "width": 80,
                                "height": 40,
                                "pixelMapperLogo": true,
                                "imageURL": "http://pixelmap.amcharts.com/static/img/logo.svg",
                                "url": "http://www.amcharts.com"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "balloon": {
                        "horizontalPadding": 15,
                        "borderAlpha": 0,
                        "borderThickness": 1,
                        "verticalPadding": 15
                    },
                    "areasSettings": {
                        "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
                        "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
                        "rollOverOutlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
                        "rollOverBrightness": 20,
                        "selectedBrightness": 20,
                        "selectable": true,
                        "unlistedAreasAlpha": 0,
                        "unlistedAreasOutlineAlpha": 0
                    },
                    "imagesSettings": {
                        "alpha": 1,
                        "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
                        "outlineAlpha": 0,
                        "rollOverOutlineAlpha": 0,
                        "outlineColor": "rgba(80,80,80,1)",
                        "rollOverBrightness": 20,
                        "selectedBrightness": 20,
                        "selectable": true
                    },
                    "linesSettings": {
                        "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
                        "selectable": true,
                        "rollOverBrightness": 20,
                        "selectedBrightness": 20
                    },
                    "zoomControl": {
                        "zoomControlEnabled": true,
                        "homeButtonEnabled": false,
                        "panControlEnabled": false,
                        "right": 38,
                        "bottom": 30,
                        "minZoomLevel": 0.25,
                        "gridHeight": 100,
                        "gridAlpha": 0.1,
                        "gridBackgroundAlpha": 0,
                        "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
                        "draggerAlpha": 1,
                        "buttonCornerRadius": 2
                    }
                });
        </script>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );

                    color = "#000000";

                    document.getElementsByClassName("amcharts-map-area-FR")[0].setAttribute("fill", color);
                }
    );

    $( window ).load(function() {
        console.log( "window loaded" );
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0;background-color: rgba(80,80,80,1);">
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 767px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this problem can be solved !

Thanks !

Comment: I don't see any element with `class="amcharts-map-area-FR"`.

Comment: The AmCharts library does the whole thing and create <path> element.

Comment: Probably, the library crates the element asynchronously. So when you use `getElementsByClassName`, the element is not there yet. Search if the library allows you to set a callback to be run once finished.

Comment: Then how can I be sure that the element is already set ?

Comment: `if ( document.contains(elementReference) { // Do stuff }`

Answer (score 0):

Your code to manipulate fill color of the area is correct. However, it executes immediately on page load. At that point the map is still initializing, meaning there's no such element yet, hence it not working.

There are a number of ways to go about it.

If you just need to load the map with certain areas (countries) colored, you could do that with map's config:

```
"dataProvider": {
  "map": "worldLow",
  "getAreasFromMap": true,
  "areas": [ {
    "id": "FR",
    "color": "#00FF00"
  } ],
  "images": [ {
    "top": 40,
    "left": 60,
    "width": 80,
    "height": 40,
    "pixelMapperLogo": true,
    "imageURL": "http://pixelmap.amcharts.com/static/img/logo.svg",
    "url": "http://www.amcharts.com"
  } ]
}
```

If that is not acceptable, or if you need to manipulate the map after it's built, I suggest you use map's API functions ([`getObjectById()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#getObjectById) to get area object, then [`validate()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapArea#validate) to refresh it) to manipulate area colors, rather than CSS.

You would also need to ensure that map is initialized before doing so. We can use [`init`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#init) event for that.

Consider the following code:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("map", {
  "type": "map",
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": function(event) {
      var area = event.chart.getObjectById("FR");
      area.color = "#000000";
      area.validate();
    }
  }]
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6f2fd1c4fbc70877d14c7e4a8c0ec5af).

You could use the same event to manipulate color of the area using your CSS code, however I strongly suggest using API functions. While manipulating CSS directly may work, the changes might be reset when there's something going on on the map, such as when you hover the area.